# How to print table column values counts in the welcome.blade.php

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

I am working with Larvel 5.6 and I have table name as **projects** with following columns

```
id    projectName          type
1    abc             finance
2   sxc             marckting
3   dgt             IT
4   hng             finance
5   hng             IT
6   gtf             finance       
etc
```

now I need count numbers of each type of the project table and print it on welcome.blade.php file like this

```
finance(3)    marckting(1)   IT(2)  etc
```

how can do this?

Comment: Mention what you have tried so far

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
$projects = Project::groupBy('type')->select('id', 'type', \DB::raw('COUNT(*) as cnt'))->get();
```

You can pass the variable to blade template from your controller like this:

```
return $this->view('welcome', compact('projects'));
```

Finally you iterate it on the welcome blade template like this:

```
@foreach($projects as $project)
    {{ $project->type }} ({{ $project->cnt }})
@endforeach
```

You can be sure the "welcome.blade.php" file is in the correct path.

Comment: How can I print above count values on blade file?

Comment: You can did it with define a variable like "$projects". Then you can iterate it with "foreach" statement. I will explain it inside the answer..